# Designing UI of Android apps to make it look the same across all phone models?

Tags: java, android, mobile

When designing a website, you have to take special considerations to make sure that the website won't break on various screen resolutions.

When designing an Android app, are there any considerations like these too? Or are all Android mobiles around the same screen size/resolution that an App working on the emulator will work on all/most phone models running Android?

Comment: Android devices come in different screen sizes/densities and you have to take this in consideration when designing/building an app. See this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks, post that as answer with a little more detail if you'd like, and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android we can use ***screen size selector***, introduced from ***Android 3.2***, to define which layout to use. 
More details available at http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html. Following code snippet has been extracted from the same link :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) 
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_tablet);
        } 
        else 
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        }
    }
}
```

Another good reference for size configuration is keeping separator. This is explain in details at : http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, `Android` devices come in different screen sizes and densities. This is something that you have to take in consideration when building an app if you want to provide a quality app that the user will enjoy and use.

Regarding screen sizes, you could let `Android` work its magic and modify your single layouts to the different devices out there. This will work but the app's quality will  decrease. A simple example would be the layout differences between a smartphone and a tablet. A layout with a `ListView` widget will look well on a smartphone but not on a  10' inch tablet(where you could/should provide more functionality on a single screen).

You'll have to take in consideration the density of the screen to provide a great look of your app, otherwise relying on the default system will decrease your app's visual appeal on a great number of devices out there.

I don't know if this is what you're targeting with your question but there are a lot(or a decent amount) of changes from an API level to the next API level as the `Android` platform evolves. If you are using API's that are available only on the newer versions, you have to take care and either port that functionality on older versions(of course if you intend to support them) or make your app to simply avoid them in a decent manner.

You can find more on the official android site, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), those are best practices that an android developer should always use for the apps he's building.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that one should develop two versions of the UI, one for tablets and one for smartphones, and detect at runtime which UI to show?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Yes, this is something that you should think even before you write the code for the app(of course this depends on what kind of application do you build). A tablet has(usually) a bigger screen than a normal smartphone and you could use this space to add more functionality into one screen, an usability improvement for the app. This is the reason for the introduction of the fragments API, which is even available on older versions through the compatibility package.